# Library search paths

Tags: libraries

This question originally started in an apparent problem in Cups calling various back-ends and using non-standard library search paths. If I want to change a library search path for a app running in a terminal I can use LD_LIBRARY_PATH, RPATH, etc., but if I want to change a library path for a Cups back end, I subsequently resolved the Cups issue, but I don't see any mechanism to change the search path whare an app is not running in terminal.

For example Cups calls backendA and backendB to print on 2 printers, BackendA uses libxxx.1.15 and BackendB needs libxxx.1.05, is there any way to change the library search path for backendB (only) without recompiling backendB, (I may not have the source)?

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how easy changing the library search path is, but I recommend using symlinks to the libraries instead. That would be much easier, and would probably work better

Comment: But a symlink would change the library access for all apps, I only want to change the accessed library for 1 app and leave the system default for the other(s).